# Google Cloud Platform submit training job, how to read USER_ARGS from training code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am submitting a training job on google cloud platform using

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME
               --scale-tier basic
               --package-path $TRAINING_PACKAGE_PATH
               --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE
               --job-dir $JOB_DIR
               --runtime-version $RUNTIME_VERSION
               --python-version $PYTHON_VERSION
               --region $REGION
```

My training code looks somehow like the one in the online tutorial [cloudml-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/sklearn/iris_training.py).
From [Packaging a Training Application](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer) guide, I saw you can pass parameters to the training job by adding

```
-- \
--user_first_arg=first_arg_value \
--user_second_arg=second_arg_value
```

But anywhere I could find how to read the params from the training code. Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: You need to define flags accordingly in your training program. The service will pass the user args as flags to your training program.

Comment: yeah but how? is there a code example somewhere I can look? what's the procedure to read the flags in the training program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this new [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/training/tensorflow/structured/base/trainer/task.py).

You have `task.py` which reads parameters from `gcloud` command

which pass the inputs to `model.py` which exists in [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/training/tensorflow/structured/base/trainer/model.py) file.

Comment: great, so it is like reading normal flags from a script, I thought that wouldn't work.

Comment: In my case, it's actually unable to read the cmd args. Not sure why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I know I probably used my dockerfile incorrectly, but to accept user args, my gcloud query looked like this:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME  /
--region $REGION   /
--master-image-uri $IMAGE_URI   /
--  /
app.py --user_first_arg=first_arg_value
```

Dockerfile

```
...
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

app.py

```
def get_args():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--user_first_arg',
      default=0)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  return args

def main():
  args = get_args()
  print(args.user_first_arg)
...
```